# How to create Sphinx index from a specific or custom docstring element?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

Is it possible to create an index in Sphinx which is created by specific (or custom) elements in the docstring?

For example, I have the following function and would like to have Sphinx to create an index from the field "Command Reference".

Is this possible and what would I have to do?

```
def get_software_version(self):
    """
    Gets the software version 

    Examples
    --------
    100000 = V1.00 

    Command Reference
    -----------------
    CSWVE

    Returns
    -------
    version: string
       version number as string
    """
```

Comment: No. However you can use [sphinx-quickstart](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html) to generate the initial index.rst file or [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) for automatic generation of Sphinx sources that, using the autodoc extension, document a whole package in the style of other automatic API documentation tools.

Comment: If you mean "create an index **entry**", take a look at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#index-generating-markup

Comment: It is not clear what "create Sphinx index from a specific or custom docstring element" means.